# How to update old certificates in docker container filesystem

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, certificate

I need to update certificates that are currently in docker containers running via kubernetes pods. The three pods containing these certificates are titled 'app', 'celery' and 'celery beat'

When I run

`kubectl exec -it app -- sh`

and then `ls`

I can see that the old certificates are there. I have new certificates on my VM filesystem and need to get these into the running pods so the program starts to work again. I tried rebuilding the docker images used to create the running containers (using the existing docker compose file), but that didn't seem to work. I think the filesystem in the containers was initially mounted using docker volumes. That presumably was done locally whereas now the project is on a remote Linux VM. What would be the natural way to get the new certs into the running pods leaving everything else the same?

I can `kubectl cp` the new certs in, the issue with that is that when the pods get recreated, they revert back to the old certificates.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Canonically, you should update the images (maybe you have a line like `RUN update-ca-certs`), republish them under a new image tag, and update the Kubernetes deployments with the new `image:` value.  Volumes shouldn't be part of this, nor should `kubectl exec` nor `kubectl cp`.  Have you done these steps?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did try that but the new images weren't working on the remote machine despite working locally. The line ```RUN update-ca-certs``` is indeed in the Dockerfile, the images were created via docker compose which also has a volumes section. (I didn't build this program so don't want to reinvent the wheel, just want to get the new certificates working). Volumes are what I believe copies the files I see in the pod into the image/container? I will try this again to provide some further details

Comment: If you can [edit] the question to include a [mcve] that would be helpful.  If your Kubernetes setup injects certificates using a ConfigMap, for example, that will hide anything that's in the image.

Comment: First you need to figure out how the old certs are copied into the containers is it using secrets, configMaps or volumes, or going with minimal approach you can copy the new certs into the remote VM at the location of shared volume

Answer (score 0):

Check in your deployment file, in the volume section, if there is some mention of configmap, secret, PV or PVC with a name more likely "certs" (normally we use names like this), if it exist, and the mention is secret or configmap, you just need to update this resource directly. If the mention is a PV or PVC, you'll need to update it by CLI for example, and I suggest you to change to a secret.

Command to check your deployment resource: `kubectl get deploy <DEPLOY NAME> -o yaml` (if you don't use deployment, change it to the right resource kind).

Also, you can access your pod shell and run `df -hT` this probably will prompt your drives and mount points.

In the worst scenario when the certs were added during the container build, you can solve it by (This is not the best practice. The best practice is to build a new image):

- Edit the container image, remove the certs, push with a new tag (don't overwrite the old one).
- Create a secret with the new certs
- Mount this secret in the same path and using the same names.
- Change the image version in the deployment.

You can use the `kubectl edit deploy <DEPLOY NAME>` to edit your resource.

To edit your container image, use docker commit: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/